# What is 'as' in ruby on rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is 'as' in ruby on rails model? and how does it work?

**e.g.**

```
has_many :something, as: :reasonable
```

Is it polymorphic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a [polymorphic association](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) which allows a model to belong to multiple models. There should be

```
class Something < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reasonable, polymorphic: true
end
```

And then any model can have many of these as reasonable without adding another column to Something.

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :somethings, as: :reasonable
end

class Stuff < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :somethings, as: :reasonable
end
```

Something stores both the class and ID of what its associated with allowing it to be polymorphic.